# AutoComplete only selects value if I click on the dropdown suggestion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, textfield

```
        <Autocomplete
          disablePortal
          id="geo-select-country"
          options={all_country}
          defaultValue={nation}
          onChange={(event, selected_nation) => {
            set_nation(selected_nation);
          }}
          classes={autocomplete_classes}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField {...params} label={"Country"} margin="none" focused />
          )}
        />
```

For example, if I type out "United States" and then click enter or click away, nothing will be selected. I would have to click on the dropdown suggestion for "United States" in order for it to be selected.

Why do I fix this?

EDITED:

Here is a live example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-frost-9cj0v?file=/src/App.js

Values can only be selected if you actually click them in the dropdown. Even if you type the value exactly as it is suggested and then click enter, it will not be selected.

Comment: how about using it with `autoHighlight={true}` prop ?

Comment: This worked if `ENTER` is pressed. But if I click outside of the `AutoComplete` after typing a valid value, it will be discarded. What is the fix for the later?

Comment: I think `autoSelect={true}` will solve later problem

Comment: both worked, thanks

Comment: You're welcome, Is it ok to post it as answer?

Comment: Why not? Not sure why you didn't post it as an answer to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve selecting value by pressing `Enter`, you can use `autoHighlight={true}` prop and also in order to solve the clicking outside issue, you can use `autoSelect={true}` with `Autocomplete`.